# Really complex LINQ (to SQL) query example

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, orm

We're thinking about adding more LINQ tests for ORMBattle.NET, but have no more ideas. All LINQ tests there are checking common LINQ functionality:

- Any test must pass on LINQ to IEnumerable
- For any test, there must be at least one ORM, on it passes (actually it doesn't matter if it is listed @ ORMBattle or not).

Currently the goal of LINQ test sequence is to *automatically* compute LINQ implementation coverage score.

**Prerequisites:**

- [Code of tests for LINQ to SQL is here](http://code.google.com/p/ormbattle/source/browse/trunk/Tests/Linq/Linq2Sql.generated.cs). This must give some imagination of what's already covered.
- Tests for other tools (actually they're generated by [this T4 template](http://code.google.com/p/ormbattle/source/browse/trunk/Tests/Linq/LinqTests.tt)) are [here](http://code.google.com/p/ormbattle/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Tests/Linq).

If you have any ideas on what can be added there, please share them. I'll definitely accept *any* example of LINQ query that satisfies above requirements, and possibly - some good idea related to improvement of test suite, that *can be implemented* (so e.g. if you'd suggest us to manually study the quality of translation, this won't work, because we can't automate this).

Comment: "Tests for support of exotic types and methods can be rejected. "Exotic" means it will be recognized as exotic by majority of ORM vendors @ ORMBattle.NET Development Google Group." Then ask the *majority* who has the right to approve tests to create the tests. They can basically reject anything they like by recognizing it as "exotic."

Comment: Is the question "contribute some stuff to my project?"  This doesn't seem to be the proper forum for that.

Comment: Ok, to clear this up: if you'd use e.g. Uri type in your test, there is a huge chance it will be recognized as exotic - simply because there is no similar type in relational scope, but the other hand, most likely it's possible to simulate some of its method using string operations.

Comment: On the other hand, I hardly believe type like Uri will be supported by at least one ORM or LINQ provider in next few years. Ok, I'll remove condition 3 - 1 & 2 define the scope well enough.

Comment: > Is the question "contribute some stuff to my project?"
Yes, partially - i.e. you must know pretty exotic context to answer it. But the question is related to coding, requires expert knowledge and likely, can be answered in just few LOC. So I was not fully sure and decided to try this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `Expression.Invoke` for subexpressions; works on LINQ-to-SQL and LINQ-to-Objects, but not EF in 3.5SP1 (for `IEnumerable<T>`, call `.AsQueryable()` first):

   ```
       Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> pred1 = cust=>cust.Country=="UK";
       Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> pred2 = cust=>cust.Country=="France";
       var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "x");
       var final = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(
           Expression.OrElse(
               Expression.Invoke(pred1, param),
               Expression.Invoke(pred2, param)
           ), param);
       using (var ctx = new DataClasses1DataContext())
       {
           ctx.Log = Console.Out;
           int ukPlusFrance = ctx.Customers.Count(final);
       }
   ```

   example LINQ-to-SQL output (EF explodes in sparks):

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
   FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [t0]
   WHERE ([t0].[Country] = @p0) OR ([t0].[Country] = @p1)
   -- @p0: Input NVarChar (Size = 2; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [UK]
   -- @p1: Input NVarChar (Size = 6; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [France]
   ```
2. identity-manager short-circuit without roundtrip - i.e.

   ```
   var obj = ctx.Single(x=>x.Id == id);
   var obj = ctx.Where(x=>x.Id == id).Single();
   ```

   etc should *not* need to go to the database if an object with that identity has already been materialized and stored in the identity-manager; applies also to `First`, `SingleOrDefault`, `FirstOrDefault`. See LINQ-to-SQL (also [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=340036) and [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=362313); you can verify by attaching to `.Log`); example:

   ```
   using (var ctx = new DataClasses1DataContext())
   {
       ctx.Log = Console.Out;
       var first = ctx.Customers.First();
       string id = first.CustomerID;
       Console.WriteLine("Any more trips?");
       var firstDup = ctx.Customers.First(x=>x.CustomerID==id);
       Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(first, firstDup)); // true
       Console.WriteLine("Prove still attached");
       int count = ctx.Customers.Count();
   }
   ```

   log output shows only only two trips; one to get the object the first time, and one for the count; it also shows the same object reference is returned by the materializer:

   ```
   SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[CustomerID], [t0].[CompanyName], [t0].[ContactName], [t0].[
   ContactTitle], [t0].[Address], [t0].[City], [t0].[Region], [t0].[PostalCode], [t
   0].[Country], [t0].[Phone], [t0].[Fax]
   FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [t0]
   -- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 3.5.30729.492
   6

   Any more trips?
   True <==== this is object reference equality, not "are there any more trips"
   Prove still attached
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
   FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [t0]
   -- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 3.5.30729.492
   6
   ```
3. UDF support; for a simple example that also works for LINQ-to-Objects:

   ```
   partial class MyDataContext {
        [Function(Name="NEWID", IsComposable=true)] 
        public Guid Random()  { return Guid.NewGuid();}
   }
   ```

   and then order by `x => ctx.Random()`; example:

   ```
   using (var ctx = new DataClasses1DataContext())
   {
       ctx.Log = Console.Out;
       var anyAtRandom = (from cust in ctx.Customers
                          orderby ctx.Random()
                          select cust).First();
   }
   ```

   with output:

   ```
   SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[CustomerID], [t0].[CompanyName], [t0].[ContactName], [t0].[        ContactTitle], [t0].[Address], [t0].[City], [t0].[Region], [t0].[PostalCode], [t0].[Country], [t0].[Phone], [t0].[Fax]
   FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [t0]
   ORDER BY NEWID()
   ```
4. If I was feeling *truly* evil, [recursive lambda](http://blogs.msdn.com/madst/archive/2007/05/11/recursive-lambda-expressions.aspx); probably not worth supporting this in *any* way... likewise, 4.0 expression (DLR) node-types.

Comment: Thanks a lot! We'll definitely add 1 & 3 to tests. 2 seems pretty subjective (e.g. we decided to not spend any time on this) + implies SQL query detection (currently tests don't pay attention to SQL), so I'll ask the others. 4 is, likely, not supported by anyone, since this must imply ~ UDF generation. So let's leave this until some leave proof ;) And I agree, 4 is interesting mainly as a tricky case. But may be we'll add a test for successful detection of recursive lambda.

Comment: P.S. Marc, you're a real expert :) I hardly expected to get something new here (I thinking mainly about something like specific VB.NET methods), but case 1 was absolutely new for me. I'll ask the guys from our team - may be they knew about this. Although this seems improbable.