# Which ORM tools support this version of Queryable.Select extension method

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, orm, linq-to-entities

Do you know an ORM supporting this extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(
  this IQueryable<TSource> source, 
  Expression<Func<TSource, int, TResult>> selector)
```

Basically, it allows to add row number (index of result in sequence) to the projection. Example of its usage with `IEnumerable` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269058/how-do-you-add-an-index-field-to-linq-results). But the same method exists for `IQueryable`.

So I'm curious, is there any ORM tool that supports this method?

The question is actually related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870082/really-complex-linq-to-sql-query-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No examples, so most likely there is no such ORM.

Comment: We've finally implemented this stuff in DataObjects.Net.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use it with LINQ to Entities. Since it's just icing over the standard `Select`, I would presume that any `IQueryable` provider which supports `Select` would also work with it.

Bear in mind, though: It's *not* the row number, as evidenced by the fact that it's an `Int32`. It's an [index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534638.aspx), which isn't the same thing.

Comment: Actually I'm not as sure as you are: I didn't find any links so far approving this. But it seems a good idea to add test for this to ORMBattle. If this is approved, your answer will be accepted :)

Comment: So the document you just posted to another my question (about list of supported IQueryable methods for EF) explicitly states this method isn't supported by EF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550(VS.100).aspx (see second item).

Comment: I've certainly used it before, but can't think of a good way to search for it. It's certainly possible I went through `AsEnumerable` first. At any rate, it certainly *should not* be a row number no matter how you do it.

Comment: Err... Do you mean it's desirable to avoid using row numbers? If so, that's true, and I know this.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I only brought it up because of what your question actually says.