# LINQ display row numbers

Tags: sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

I simply want to include a row number against the returned results of my query.

I found the following post that describes what I am trying to achieve but gives me an exception

http://vaultofthoughts.net/LINQRowNumberColumn.aspx

"An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator"

In MS SQL I would just use the ROWNUMBER() function, I'm simply looking for the equivalent in LINQ.

Comment: can we have your own LINQ query, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AsEnumerable()` to evaluate the final part of your query on the client, and in that final part add a counter column:

```
int rowNo = 0;
var results = (from data in db.Data
               // Add any processing to be performed server side
               select data)
              .AsEnumerable()
              .Select(d => new { Data = d, Count = ++rowNo });
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether LINQ to SQL supports it (but it propably will), but there's an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534638.aspx) to the [Queryable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.select.aspx) method that accepts an lambda with an indexer. You can write your query as follows:

```
db.Authors.Select((author, index) => new
{
    Lp = index, Name = author.Name
});
```

**UPDATE:**

I ran a few tests, but unfortunately LINQ to SQL does not support this overload (both 3.5sp1 and 4.0). It throws a `NotSupportedException` with the message:

> Unsupported overload used for query
>   operator 'Select'.

Comment: -1: There is no `Queryable.Select` which passes an index to the delegate.

Comment: @Richard: Did you even bother to check this? Here is the overload I talked about: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534638.aspx. Please reevaluate your negative vote.

Comment: I had seen confirmation (but I can't find where now -- of course): ORMs typically don't implement it. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873850/which-orm-tools-support-this-version-of-queryable-select-extension-method/1905527

Comment: @Richard: I've did a little test, and you're right. Unfortunately, L2S does not support this (both 3.5 and 4.0). I thought of removing my answer, but perhaps this information and our discussion is still of some use to someone.

Comment: Removed the -1, with the caveat that some LINQ providers (L2S being significant here) don't support this.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to SQL allows you to map a SQL function. While I've not tested this, I think this construct will work:

```
public partial class YourDataContext : DatContext
{
    [Function(Name = "ROWNUMBER")]
    public int RowNumber()
    {
        throw InvalidOperationException("Not called directly.");
    }
}
```

And write a query as follows:

```
from author in db.Authors
select new { Lp = db.RowNumber(), Name = author.Name };
```